# python pandas loop through dataframe return dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this.

```
frame =  pd.DataFrame({'home'    : ['CHI', 'ATL', 'SEA', 'DET', 'STL','HOU' ,'CHI','CHI'],
                     'away'    : ['DET', 'CHI', 'HOU', 'TOR', 'DAL', 'STL', 'MIA', 'SEA'],
                     'awayPTS' : [88, 75, 105, 99, 110, 85, 95, 100],
                     'homePTS' : [92, 88, 95, 97, 100, 74, 98, 110],
                      'week' : [1, 1, 1, 2, 2,3, 3, 4]})
```

I can get the output I want by doing this

```
uniqueTeams = frame['home'].unique()

def _earlyGamesPTS(n):
   for team in uniqueTeams:
       homePTS = frame['homePTS'][(frame.week <= n) & (frame.home == team)].sum()
       awayPTS = frame['awayPTS'][(frame.week <= n) & (frame.away == team)].sum()
       totalPTS = homePTS+ awayPTS
       print team, totalPTS
```

Running that function prints the desired information.

I am having trouble having the function **return** the values I want.

```
def _earlyGamesPTS(n):
    for team in uniqueTeams:
        homePTS = frame['homePTS'][(frame.week <= n) & (frame.home == team)].sum()
        awayPTS = frame['awayPTS'][(frame.week <= n) & (frame.away == team)].sum()
        totalPTS = homePTS+ awayPTS
    return team, totalPTS
```

only returns one set of values.  I am pretty sure the indentation is correct.

Why is it doing that and how can I get it to return a dictionary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's better to do it using the pandas groupby:

```
# Limit the week
limited = frame[frame['week'] <= n]
# Calculate the home and away points
home_points= limited.groupby('home').sum()['homePTS']
away_points = limited.groupby('away').sum()['awayPTS']
# Sum them
home_points.add(away_points, fill_value=0)
```

This gives me (for n=3):

```
ATL     88
CHI    265
DAL    110
DET    185
HOU    179
MIA     95
SEA     95
STL    185
TOR     99
```

To fix your solution you can append every iteration to a list:

```
uniqueTeams = set(frame['home']) | set(frame['away'])

def _earlyGamesPTS(n):
    all_teams = []
    for team in uniqueTeams:
        homePTS = frame['homePTS'][(frame.week <= n) &
                                   (frame.home == team)].sum()
        awayPTS = frame['awayPTS'][(frame.week <= n) &
                                   (frame.away == team)].sum()
        totalPTS = homePTS+ awayPTS
        all_teams.append([team, totalPTS])
    return all_teams
```

Which (for the same n=3) gives:

```
[['TOR', 99],
 ['DAL', 110],
 ['STL', 185],
 ['CHI', 265],
 ['ATL', 88],
 ['DET', 185],
 ['MIA', 95],
 ['HOU', 179],
 ['SEA', 95]]
```

Comment: BTW in pandas git master, there's a new `DataFrame.query()` method. You could use it here like `frame['homePTS'].query('week <= n and home == team')`

Comment: Or even better is `frame.homePTS.query('week <= n and home == team')`.

Comment: @PhillipCloud I never got to ask you: why was it decided to use strings instead of queries similar to sqlalchemy, django or whatever other flavour there is? I mean, nobody is really a fan of "string programming" :-/ It's horribly error prone, "sql injection" prone, not available for static analysis and a thousand more things... Or it's just a first step toward a full query system in some of the future releases?

Comment: I'm not familiar with sqlalchemy/django queries. I'm guessing they are a way to map a db onto objects. One reason we chose to use strings is because `numexpr` takes strings. The parser is `ast.parse` with a few bells and whistles (so, e.g, syntax errors are propagated). We also wanted to allow for future engines in the backend, e.g., `numba`. Not sure I follow why SQL injection is an issue in this case. I suppose a more general sort of "injection" attack is possible, but the parser takes care to disallow anything except expressions (no functions). Would love help in trying to break things :)

Comment: @PhillipCloud Yes I meant general injection, thats why I added quotations :) SA/DJ queries are basically doing the same thing: generating string SQL queries but using a query object that can be checked in static analysis (and also checks for injections in runtime). But I assume that once you have the string version implemented, implementing the query system will be a much simpler task if the need for it shows up :)